# How does this for loop on consecutive integers work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This seems like an embarrassingly easy concept but I can't understand why this for loop is working the way it is. The question is simply asking "Given a binary array, find the maximum number of consecutive 1s in this array."

```
def main(nums):
 count = 0
 for num in nums:
   if num == 1:
    count+=1
   else:
    count = 0 
main([1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1])
```

My question is, why does this for loop work? I expected the loop to print out the total count of 1's.

Comment: Why do you need the `else`? Besides, the indentation isn't very clear

Comment: @MosesKoledoye If I take out the else statement then it adds up the counts all 1's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just doesn't work.

You can't expect to have the sum of all the 1s because when the loop find a zero it reset the counter (the "else" part).

However, your code doesn't do what it was expected to do, add a zero at the end of the list and you will easily see that the code fails.

To do what you asked, without changing your code too much, try this

```
def main(nums):
    count = maxcount = 0
    for num in nums:
        if num == 1:
            count+=1
        else:
            maxcount=max(maxcount, count)
            count = 0
    return maxcount
print(main([1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1]))
```

Dave

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that once it sees a zero, it sets the value of `count` back down to zero, saying that it's seen 0 consecutive ones. This code actually doesn't work—it only gets lucky on this input because the longest sequence is at the very end of the list.

A better practice would be to store both the lengths of the `current_group` of ones and the `highest_total` count.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably hard to believe, but could it be that the reason you are wondering why this loop works at all is that you are not familiar with Python ability to iterate over all elements of a list, not needing any counter variable increasing its value?

> [1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]

is in Python a kind of array storing multiple number of values.

Here some "pseudo-code" for explanatory purpose only demonstrating that `"for num in nums"` means in Python (in terms of programming in other 
languages which don't support iteration over elements of a list/array):

```
noOfValuesIn_nums = lengthOf/sizeOf(nums)
for i = 0 to noOfValuesIn_nums do: 
   # get i=th value from 'nums' and put it to a variable named 'num':
   num = nums[i]
   ...
```

By the way: the loop provided in the question gives the desired result for the provided example:
main([1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1])
but won't work on another one as demonstrated here:

```
def main(nums):
     count = 0
     for num in nums:
         if num == 1:
             count+=1
         else:
             count = 0 
     return count

print( main([1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1]) )
# it prints 1 instead of 6
```

The task of finding the longest consecutive sequence of ones
solves following code:

```
def main1(nums):
     count = 0
     maxOnes = 0
     for num in nums:
         if num == 1:
             count+=1
         else:
             if count > maxOnes:
                 maxOnes = count
             count = 0 
     return maxOnes
print( main1([1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1]) )
# gives 6
```